# JavaFX node's bounds not updated when maximizing

Tags: javafx

I am developing a JavaFX control, that draws lines between its child components. Those child  components grow when there is room. To draw lines between them, I am working a lot with **Node.getBoundsInParent()**, called whenever the control's size changes.
That all works fine, when I resize the window.

When I maximize the window, the components grow and are layouted as expected. Since the controls size changed, the bounds are read again - but they are still in the state before maximizing the window.
When I stop maximizing the window, the size changes calling *getBoundsInParent()* returns the maximized sizes of the components.

I tried to explicitly listen to the Window maximizing event and call requestLayout() on my control, but the effect is still the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem. Depending on exactly what you mean by "control" you should either be laying out the lines in `layoutChildren` or the lines should be bound to the components. Either approach should preclude the need for calling `requestLayout`.

Comment: It* would be best...

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it helped that when triggering a redraw, I had to put that redraw in a Platform.runLater() call.  That worked for resizing and maximizing as well.

Comment: typically, runlater is _not_ required to make things work when changing stuff _in the view_ -  smells like something wrong in your setup or a corner case (no way to tell as you insisted on not providing a [mcve] ;)